# Tool to Build Abstract Syntax Trees

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a tool available on Windows, Linux and Mac so as to build Python codes building abstract syntax trees. Is there such a kind of tool ?

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is considered off-topic. Ignoring that though, it's unclear what you mean by "build Python codes building abstract syntax trees"... Do you want diagrams? Just AST's that can be navigated via code/used for something etc... etc...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html ?

Comment: Indeed, I'm looking for a general tool.

Comment: @Jon Clements: I want to parse some language such as to do analysis of code, coloration... I've invented an easy-to-use DSL for defining my grammars. The next steps is to have tool that will build the abstract trees for further use like the ones I want.

Comment: What you really want is a program transformation engine.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the vocabulary. I'm a french frog... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR has a runtime available for Python; it generates code which generates ASTs.  I've used the C++ version of ANTLR and it works great.

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Python+runtime

Comment: I will play with that. Thanks. I was persuaded that ANT was only for C/C++...